# Is it possible to use Google Cloud Storage CloudStorageTools::serve with PHP Zip?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a set of confidential files in Google Cloud Storage that I allow people to download one at a time using [CloudStorageTools::serve](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/public_access). It would be more convenient if they could select a group of files and download them in a zip file. I am using PHP with Google App Engine and see that PHP has a [ZipArchive class](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php).

I don't see a straightforward way to create a zip file using CloudStorageTools:serve, which for times sake would be my preferred method. If someone knows how to do this, that would be very helpful.

If it's not possible, it would seem a lot of other options may work, from momentarily turning the files into public accessible, which would give them a public URL that I could use to create the zip files. I would prefer to avoid this because of the confidentiality issue. Another option would be to temporarily copy them to a folder in Google App Engine, zip them and then delete them. Again, I have concerns with confidentiality. Both these methods seem somewhat time consuming to setup. So if someone has a faster/better method, I would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out it's much simpler than I presumed. I just needed to access the files directly from Google Cloud Storage. Problem is that there is a bug and it doesn't work regardless, here's a link to the bug, https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11010&thanks=11010&ts=1402415512